# coreapi : can not get schema

Tags: python, json, request, client, content-type

python 3.7

I have a python app for which I run tests:

```
$ python -m unittest
```

package code goes like this:

```
import coreapi
from coreapi import codecs

class myClient():

    myApiUrl = None

    client = None

    def __init__(self, myApiUrl, authenticationToken):

        self.myApiUrl = myApiUrl

        auth = coreapi.auth.TokenAuthentication(
            scheme='Token',
            token=authenticationToken
        )

        decoders = [
            codecs.CoreJSONCodec(),
            codecs.JSONCodec()
        ]

        self.client = coreapi.Client(auth=auth, decoders=decoders)


    def getSomething(self):
        ....at this point self.client.decoders are present....
        schema = self.client.get(self.myApiUrl)
        .......blah-blah....
```

This tests run ends with this error:

> ERROR: test_doFirstTest (myclient.tests.SomeTestClass)
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/usr/src/app/myclient/tests.py", line 82, in test_doFirstTest
>
>      output = client.test_doFirstTest()    File "/usr/src/app/myclient/myClient.py", line 42, in getSomething
>
>      schema = self.client.get(self.myApiUrl)    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coreapi/client.py", line 136, in get
>
>      return transport.transition(link, decoders, force_codec=force_codec)    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coreapi/transports/http.py", line 380, in transition
>
>      result = _decode_result(response, decoders, force_codec)    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coreapi/transports/http.py", line 284, in _decode_result
>
>      codec = utils.negotiate_decoder(decoders, content_type)    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coreapi/utils.py", line 207, in negotiate_decoder
>
>      raise exceptions.NoCodecAvailable(msg)  coreapi.exceptions.NoCodecAvailable: Unsupported media in Content-Type header 'text/html'
> ```

I realise it's telling me that it received text/html instead of json (maybe an empty string?), but why? I am not doing any request yet, I am doing a preparation step of getting the schema object.

And this is not a connectivity issue, when it can not connect at all it gives different error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok this did not have anything to do with coreapi, codex, unittest, requests, or anything I could possible think of. The reason for that error is some docker container involved was exiting silently after starting because another docker container on which the first one depends was not started. So the manifestation just happened to be non-decipherable.